# How to evaluate a parameterized surface integral?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, parametrization

Suppose you have to evaluate the surface integral $$\int\int_S (x^2+y^2+4)\space dS$$ where $S$ is the surface parameterized by $\textbf{r} = <2uv, u^2-v^2, u^2+v^2>$ with $u^2+v^2 \le 16.$

I know the equation to solve the surface integral is $$\int\int_S f \space dS = \int\int_S f(\textbf{r}(u,v))\space |\textbf{r}_u \times \textbf{r}_v |\space du \space dv$$ and I will have no trouble taking the cross product or evaluating the integral. However, how would one go about finding the limits for $S$? I don't even remotely know what $\textbf{r} = <2uv, u^2-v^2, u^2+v^2>$ might be. Is there some way maybe to transform $\textbf{r}$ to an explicit $z = f(x,y)$?

Thanks.

Comment: The domain in the right handed double integral is not the same of the left handed one. In fact, the domain in the right handed integral is the parametrization's domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need know how the surface is. Notice that the domain of the parametrizations is a disc of radius 4.

Hint: Since the domain is a disc, try integrate the right hand double integral by using polar coordinates.

I hope I have helped you.

Comment: So $S$ is not the entire surface?

Comment: $S$ is given by the parametrization. What do you mean with entire surface?

Comment: The limits for S in $\int\int_S$ are not for the entire surface?

Comment: You write this: where $S$ is the surface parameterized by $r=\langle 2uv,u^2−v^2,u^2+v^2\rangle$ with $u^2+v^2\leq16$. So, your entire surface is given by this parametrization

Comment: For example, if your surface $S$ is given by $r=\langle u,v,u+v\rangle$ where $0\leq u\leq 1$ and $0\leq v\leq 1$, then the surface is a piece of a plane and this is the entire surface